# Is there something like 700%?

Tags: percentages, percentile

I always see companies advertising their products as "700% effective " or "the product kills 900% germs". 
But percent means "out of hundred". So how can the percentage be more than 100 like 700% or 900%?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't say something like: "The product kills 900% *more* germs"?

Comment: Yeah something like that.

Comment: Some exact quotes may help.  In some contexts, more than 100% would not make sense but in others it might.  It might be more of a question of English than of maths.  It depends on what 100% represents: some absolute limit that cannot be exceeded or just an arbitrary reference point which could be.

Answer (score 2):

700% would mean that it's 7 times as effective than a previous product or another company's product.

Comment: 7 times more effective, or 7 times as effective? :p

Comment: thanks, just changed it

Comment: Yeah. But isn't that wrong? Since for comparison mostly companies say "7X". Isn't using percentage in these cases wrong?

Comment: @proneon True, almost everybody says 7X. I'm just nitpicking. By contrast, I do not recommend saying _100% more effective_ when what you mean is that there is no difference ;) (My comments are irrelevant to your question. Don't let them confuse you.)

Comment: Thanks for helping.

Comment: @proneon No, it's not really wrong. To say that something is $7$ times better is exactly the same, mathematically, as saying $700\%$ better. Because $\% = 1/100$ we have that $700\% = 700\times\frac{1}{100} = 7.$ Perhaps linguistically it may be confusing, though.